# Sencha Touch 2. Get request GET params

Tags: get, request, sencha-touch-2

My url looks like http://www.mysite.com/?action=top&id=5
or (through mod_rewrite) http://www.mysite.com/top/5

How can I get GET params in Sencha Touch? Search in Internet not give me working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would probably help you:

```
Ext.Object.fromQueryString(window.location.search.substring(1));
```

This does not work for the mod_rewrite example though so maybe check that window.location.search.length > 0 and if it isn't do some regexp to filter out the /top/5 part.

**Edit:** Changed the code due to the fact that Ext.urlDecode is now deprecated. Here is the doc link to the preferred method (Ext.Object.fromQueryString)
[docs.sencha.com - fromQueryString](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Object-method-fromQueryString)

Thanks **indapublic** for the correction!

Comment: urlDecode deprecated, Sencha recommend to use Ext.Object.fromQueryString